# Split by N number of the same characters, split by the first occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I have inputs that can look like any of the following:

```
const str = 'key=value'                     // expected: str[0] == 'key', str[1] == 'value'
const str = 'key==value'                    // expected: str[0] == 'key', str[1] == 'value'
const str = 'key=value1=value2=value3'      // expected: str[0] == 'key', str[1] == 'value1=value2=value3'
const str = 'key==value1=value2'            // expected: str[0] == 'key', str[1] == 'value1=value2'
```

I'm interested in splitting by key-value pairs, getting the first occurrence of `=` or `==` and splitting by that.  I have tried:

```
var str = "this==that=these";
var spl = str.split(/==|=(.+)/);        // spl[0] == 'this', spl[1] == 'undefined'
var spl = str.split(/=|==(.+)/);        // spl[0] == 'this', spl[1] == 'undefined'
var spl = str.split(/[==]|[=](.+)/);    // spl[0] == 'this', spl[1] == 'undefined'
```

But these aren't working.  Any way to do this as a one-liner regex?

Comment: There is no need to `.split`. You may use `.match` as in `str.match(/^([^=]+)=+(.*)/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using split, you don't want to capture the actual keys or values in your RegEx, or they'll be part of the excised substrings. All you need is to do `str.split(/={1,2}/)` (which is the same as `str.split(/==|=/)` )

Comment: Thanks.  Final code: `var spl = str.split(/={1,2}(.+)/);` allows me to cover all my use-cases.